# Modificar archivo CSS desde Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, asp

Buenos días a todos,

estoy diseñando una web en ASP dónde cada usuario puede seleccionar un "tema" para la interfaz (básicamente, que el color del header y demás sea rojo, verde o azul). Lo que hago es que cada usuario, desde su página de datos personales, seleccione un color de los tres y lo guardo en la base de datos. Luego guardo ese valor dentro una variable de sesión después de que el usuario se loggee y, en el head del Site.Master, tengo lo siguiente

```
<link href="Content/StyleSheetGreen.css" rel="stylesheet" id="StyleSheet"/>
<script>document.getElementById('StyleSheet').href = "/Content/StyleSheet<%=dTema() %>.css";</script>
```

(dTema devuelve Red, Green o Blue)

El problema es que, al modificar la ruta desde Javascript, sólo carga el css en la home (www.loremipsum.com), pero al entrar en cualquier otra (www.loremipsum.com/dolor) no encuentra el fichero CSS

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano,

Andrés

Comment: Y por qué no creas 3 masterpage, una para colores rojo, otra para colores verdes y otra para colores azules. Luego por programación, dependiendo del tipo de color del usuario (indicado en la variables de sesión) muestras el masterpage correspondiente. Nota: cada masterpage apunta a un archivo css distinto, el cual tiene el diseño de colores.

Comment: Me pareció más lioso tener 3 Masterpages distintas considerando que (al menos en mi cabeza) podía hacerse cambiando sólo una línea, pero si no encuentro otra forma lo haré así. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Primero, estás modificando la hoja de estilos mediante javascript, no mediante jQuery.

Segundo, estás usando una ruta relativa (`Content/StyleSheetGreen.css`) en la carga de la hoja de estilos y luego agregas otra con ruta absoluta. Posiblemente la relativa será la que te genera esos problemas.

Asumiendo que la ruta absoluta es más fiable (no te generará problemas en subdirectorios), deberías agregar este código para generar de manera dinámica desde el servidor el archivo correcto desde el que cargar la hoja de estilos:

```
<!-- Estática, la normal -->
<link href="/Content/StyleSheetGreen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Dinámica, la buena, generada en el servidor sin intervención de javascript -->
<link href="/Content/StyleSheet<%=dTema() %>.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Es innecesario inyectar mediante javascript algo que puedes hacer directamente en el HTML desde ASP.

Comment: Si utilizo la versión dinámica no interpreta la expresión <%=dTema() %> como tal, y ejecutando me devuelve <link href="/Content/StyleSheet<%=dTema() %>.css" rel="stylesheet" /> como si fuera todo un string

Comment: Entonces parece que tu ASP no se está interpretando en el lado del servidor. ¿Te pasa lo mismo en el trozo de javascript? ¿Te sale `document.getElementById('StyleSheet').href = "/Content/StyleSheet<%=dTema() %>.css";` sin interpretar?

Comment: PD: Discúlpame pero ahora no tengo ningún IIS a mano para probar si es necesario `runat="server"`. En un rato lo miraré.

Comment: Lo peor es que no, dentro del JS si que interpreta. Y acabo de probar añadiendo el runat="server" y tampoco